# Some troubles while parsing Auth0 JWT Claims

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

```
public Map<String, String> verifyToken(final String token) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    final Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256(getPublicKey());
    final JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm).withIssuer(tokenConfiguration.getIssuer()).build();

    try {
        final DecodedJWT decodedJWT = verifier.verify(token);
        return decodedJWT.getClaims().entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, x -> x.getValue().toString()));
    } catch (final JWTVerificationException jwtVerificationException) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

I have this code which basically verify the token and retrieve claims as HashMap

```
final String phone = Optional
        .ofNullable(claimMap.get("phone"))
        .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException());
```

When I trying to get phoneNumber from Hashmap, it return correct phone but ""+1231551921"" wrong fashion. How to get rid of extra quotes?

My questions is how can i parse JWT claims with correct way ?

My jwt token with RSA-256:

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJwaG9uZSI6IjA1MzgqKio3NSoqIiwiaXNzIjoidGVzdC5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE2NDkyNTM5ODcsImp0aSI6InJlZnJlc2hfdG9rZW4ifQ.SbLRBFCjaePFu8kjmYRrBfj6iHWBJoLzABwD2d8vxIQlEM2ZZXzJ9wUCu_MiIZ7B6M5k4aRtjdg4TDEJ3HvwnAQMl63P5C46iKaDmmhg4-hx0M_alwo8f5iDuQ2BAInPiPVo4qjFQQqN_Yti0qfW2amGGwvA5yTXK1D4NONR6B7CPY1SrqPgnZ9Q2zZv039SxbsdQTtZ2u80sA2b8kmAoK69NZt6PadSFRjdXy-VMzuG5HitSvtP4xLplFGfvptHg0DrNeGEy4daqofbBXYybPbPi0VQ3mxSjYaK2EIOFOm2FJDISQ_7sZXy6pwOYepKR5CfNAzRskM_Tpf6G2Nt9g
```

Comment: Does it create the JWT claim in the correct way? You could check the actual JWT contents at https://jwt.io/

Can you share your actual JWT?

Comment: @cyberbrain hello, I add my jwt that I am trying to decode

Comment: What library are the JWT classes (DecodedJWT  etc.) from?

Comment: com.auth0.jwt.interfaces, 'com.auth0', name: 'java-jwt', version: '3.18.3'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
return decodedJWT.getClaims().entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, x -> x.getValue().toString()));
```

The dictionary values are `Claim` instances and `Claim` instances are basically pieces of JSON, so they can be a number, a string, an array or a dictionary.

If the generic `toString()` method is called, the result is formatted such that the the type can be safely distinguished, e.g.:

- `37` for a number
- `"+1231551921"` for a string
- `[ 37, "+1231551921" ]` for an array

It you are sure that your claim is of type string, call `asString()` instead of `toString()`.

Comment: What about IntNodes how can I exclude them from stream collectors

Comment: `asString()` returns `null` if the claim is not a string. So you could filter it: `.filter(x -> x.getValue().asString() != null)`